# In what program I can draw scheme as on the picture?

Tags: patterns

[image]

What software can I use to draw similar circle schemes?

The radius increase should be fixed for each subsequent circle. All 'X' should be aligned diametrically and be rotated to fit orientation.

Comment: Practically **ANY** software can create circles and Xs.

Comment: @Scott yes even paint can do that, but aligning all that circles and rotating all Xses and also making them aligned on a line looks like a nightmare for me, since I'm not familiar with graphics software.

Comment: The question doesn't ask **anything** about concentric circles or aligning characters on diameter divisions. That sample image *can* be created in practically *any* drawing/painting/sketching, etc software.

Comment: Added this to question

Comment: Yes, your probably doing the magic thing that humans sometimes do where you leave out the essential word. In this case the word is probably "Automatically". If you leave that out of your question then yes nearly darwing software can do this. Anyway, people tend to do this and it leads to comical consequences for them. Go back and write a complete question where you describe what your problem is that you would like to solve (in text, pictures are just for clarification)

Comment: And no rotating is not really a big deal. All you need to understand is that you need a tool that can define the rotation pivot.

Comment: You can make things like this in vector software, such as Illustrator, Inkscape, Affinity Designer, CorelDraw, etc. It's not automatic though. Here's a [very simplified example](https://imgur.com/bOHRylw) made in Inkscape (which is free).

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so your question is really open. but lets start from the beginning. So essentially your looking into using one of 5 categories of applications:

1. Raster editors, like Photoshop, Krita, paint, Sketchbook, Sai etc...

   Mostly youd do the exact same thing as on paper. offcourse you could use rulers and elementary transformation operations in most. even vectors but limited.

   Drawing your image would take me less than 5 minutes on any of the more complete packages. I would't choose one of these unless this really is a one off and id never need to change my mind.
2. Vector drawing software, Illustrator, Corel Draw, inkscape, affinity designer etc...

   The benefit here over the above is that your objects stay editabble much longer in the process. Its a bit less intuitive to get started. But its much less work to progress in skill to other software packages if you start here. People who start too deeply in raster editors find progressing upwards harder.

   Drawing time is 5 minutes, but changing your mind, making variations changing shape of X:es is a potentially a 30 second job.
3. A CAD package. Aurocad, Rhino, Creo... Mostly CAD packages are like  vector drawing applications but theres too much variance to say this.

   Many of the cad packages out there would actually construct your drawing semi to fully automatically. But you might be a good 6 months of learning away from this point. Again 5-10 minutes of work but potenttially could do as many rings as you want in less than 15 seconds after that.
4. TeX with something like PStricks, writing EPS in notepad, generating vectors in a webpage with javascript. again a bit of a learning curve. 5-10 minutes of work but infinite variability for 15 seconds potentially.
5. Graphing/Scientific/Math package. For example R, Mathematica, Jupiter notebooks mostly as hard as 4 and same benefits.

But at the end use what you know. Thats most likely the best tool at the moment.

PS: i wouldnt draw that image i would construct it.